# Write XML in swift on iOS

Tags: ios, xml, swift, xml-generation

I'm trying to find a solution for creating a XML Document and put it in a String, I did some research on how to create generate or write xml in swift, but I found only libraries and I don't want to use them, is there a solution?

I have some `UITextFields`, the user put values, when they click on a button, I want to create a xml document.

For exemple:
User put his name and age, when they validate I want to have this in a  string:

```
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><name>Ben</name><age>18</age>"
```

Code:

```
@IBOutlet var tfNom: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var tfPrenom: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 38.0/255.0, green: 51.0/255.0, blue: 85.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Gotham", size: 13)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
    self.title = "DEMANDE GRATUITE"
}

@IBAction func Valider(sender: AnyObject) {
    verifComplet()
    //HERE I WANT TO GET tfNom.text and tfPrenom.text AND PUT THEM INTO A XML DOCUMENT IN A STRING
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what you are trying to achieve? What have you tried? Are you aware that you can use `NSDictionary.writeToFile()` and `NSArray.writeToFile` to write the contents of a dictionary (alright, these are ObjC objects but there have to be Swift equivalents) or array to a Plist, which is in XML?

Comment: @Arc676 I have many variables, and I want to do a XML document with, thanks I'll do search on these

Comment: @EricD. no it's only for OS X

Comment: As far as I know, there is no "built-in" library on iOS which allows to *write* XML.

Comment: @MartinR There is GDataXML as librairie, but do you  know how to do without librairie ?

Comment: @Arc676 I don't find solutions do you have one ?

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to include some code? Preferably show us _what_ you want to write to an XML file and how you get the data.

Comment: @Arc676 I edited I can't past they're a lot of code sorry

Comment: Don't post your entire project, just the important parts where you store the user's input

Comment: @Arc676 look edit please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[AEXML](https://github.com/tadija/AEXML) proved to me many times that it's very handy and easy to use. Use either Cocoapods, Carthage, or simply drag and drop the only file (AEXML.swift) into your project.

Your usage:

```
let yourXML = AEXMLDocument()
let attributes = ["xmlns:xsi" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "xmlns:xsd" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"]
yourXML.addChild(name: "name", value: "Ben")
yourXML.addChild(name: "age", value: "18")
print(yourXML.xmlString)
```